# How to switch between different UIViewcontrollers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiswitch

I want to write a custom switch that will be located two custom tabBar. Its structure is as follows - [image]

I want to use uiviewcontroller.

Now I use the following code:

```
- (void)changeViewController:(NSInteger)sender{

    if(viewController){
        [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [viewController release];  
        NSLog(@"released");
    }

    switch (sender) {
        case 1:      
            viewController = [[VC1 alloc] init];
            break;
        case 2:
            viewController = [[VC2 alloc] init];
            break;
        case 3:
            viewController = [[VC3 alloc] init];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 380)];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

}
```

but I think it's wrong!

Can be used in such a structure - `presentModalViewController`, `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` or other method to work on the similarity `navigationViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.view addsubview:viewcontroller.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -  `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];`

or  `[self.navigationController popToViewController:targetController animated:YES];`

I would really subscribe `navigationController` for its memory management and a far responsive and seamless behaviour...

hope this helps.

Comment: TNX! I want to use custom navigation controller. My app containe three level. Top level is the - top tab bar. If we switch between top tabs we get different view controllers wich a containe tab bar too. In this tabs view we can see main content - this content is view controllers too. What the right way to switch between view controllers?

Comment: you can use your `custom navigation controller` in place of `self.view`. Try it out, my feeling is it should work...

Comment: popToViewController is a method on NavigationController, not on view